# New Added Files Has Been Setted Chmod 600 via FTP

Tags: settings

Whenever i've sent a file via FTP, it's chmod has been setted to 600. So they never read/run without i change to chmod.

I dont want to change this chmods everytime. 
How can i change this file's defaults ?

Thank you!

Comment: some ftp clients (filezilla, for example) can set permissions - maybe take a look at the configuration on the ftp client side?

Comment: yes i can change permissions for each file via filezilla, but i can not read global settings for server.

Comment: also i could not find any related thing into "sudo nano /etc/vsftpd.conf"

Comment: You can change the default permissions using `umask`

Answer (score 2):

You have to set **file_open_mode** value in /etc/vsftpd.conf file. Config file may not contain that key=value pair in default. Add as you want. But to enable this function you have to set **chmod_enable** value as **YES**

From the vsftpd.conf man page:

```
file_open_mode
    The permissions with which uploaded files are created. Umasks are applied on top of 
    this value. You may wish to change to 0777 if you want uploaded files to be executable.
    Default: 0666
```

**local_umask** value in /etc/vsftpd.conf file.

```
chmod_enable=YES  
file_open_mode=0644
local_umask=022
```

If you want to change umask of files that uploaded anonymously you can use **anon_umask** value.

```
anon_umask=022
```